# Checkbox has effect only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

When checkbox is checked, delete and checkbox counter button should appear like Chrome History if you check any visited page the header changes I also inlcluded this kind of part in my project but when I click first row of the table delete button appear but if I click second row it does not show.

```html
<tbody>
{% for item in items %}
    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="wpmm[]"></th>
    <td>{{ item.item_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.sku }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Here is the script:

```
var fnUpdateCount = function () {
  var generallen = $("input[name='wpmm[]']:checked").length;
  if (generallen > 0) {
    $("#general i .counter").text('(' + generallen + ')');
  } else {
    $("#general i .counter").text(' ');
  }
};

$("input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
  fnUpdateCount();
});

$('.select_all').change(function () {
  var checkthis = $(this);
  var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");

  if (checkthis.is(':checked')) {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
  }
  fnUpdateCount();
});
```

Here is the code which should show when chechbox is checked:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-between start-dash mb-4" id="general">
  <div class="col-6">
    <h4 class="text-left mt-4">Selected Items: <span class="counter"></span></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

For this this code is used:

```
$('#general').hide();
$(function () {
  $('#check').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#check').prop('checked')) {
      $('#item_info').hide();
      $('#general').show();
    } else {
      $('#item_info').show();
      $('#general').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it looks like you have multiple rows with a checkbox input, all of which have the same id. That's wrong, an id needs to be unique in the entire HTML document. Your id selector `$('#check')` only selects the first one it encounters. Use a class or other attribute.

Comment: you could use `$('input[type=checkbox]')` if you don't have any other checkbox input in the document that need a different behavior. Or add `data-myfunction` attribute to the input fields so then you can use the selector `$('input[data-myfunction]')`.

Comment: also are #item-info and #general unique divs in your document or are they also repeated? Same thing here, ids must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('change','#check', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#item_info').hide();
            $('#general').show();
        } else {
            $('#item_info').show();
            $('#general').hide();
        }
    });
});
```